# Modify arbitrary column attributes using dplyr::mutate()

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to modify column attributes inside of dplyr::mutate(). Here is some example data:

```
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
```

```
v1 <- tibble(
  id = 1:5,
  visit = 1,
  x = 1:5,
  y = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1)
)
```

The end result I would like to get is the same result I would get from:

```
attr(v1$id, "source") <- "Collected at v1"
attr(v1$visit, "source") <- "Collected at v1"
attr(v1$x, "source") <- "Collected at v1"
attr(v1$y, "source") <- "Collected at v1"
```

I know I can just use a for loop.

```
for (col in names(v1)) {
  attr(v1[[col]], "source") <- "Collected at v1"
}
```

However, I have reasons for wanting to do this inside of dplyr. I'm trying to get to something like this.

```
v1 %>% 
  mutate(
    across(
      .cols = everything(),
      .fns  = ~ function_to_update_attributes("source", "Collected at v1")
    )
  )
```

Right now, I can't even get this to work for a single variable. This is the closest I've gotten.

```
v1 %>% 
  mutate(
    id = `<-`(attr(.[["id"]], "source"), "Collected at v1")
  )
```

Which returns

```
# A tibble: 5 × 4
  id              visit     x     y
  <chr>           <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1 Collected at v1     1     1     0
2 Collected at v1     1     2     0
3 Collected at v1     1     3     0
4 Collected at v1     1     4     1
5 Collected at v1     1     5     1
```

Any constructive feedback is welcome and appreciated!

This is also posted on RStudio Community at: https://community.rstudio.com/t/modify-arbitrary-column-attributes-using-dplyr-mutate/144502

Comment: 'However, I have reasons for wanting to do this inside of dplyr' - can you explain this a bit more? do you mean dplyr specifically or tidyverse in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can directly apply the attributes on the vector with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
v1 <- v1 %>%
    mutate(across(everything(), 
     ~ {attr(.x, "source") <- "Collected at v1"
    .x} ))
```

-output

```
> str(v1)
tibble [5 × 4] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ id   : int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
  ..- attr(*, "source")= chr "Collected at v1"
 $ visit: num [1:5] 1 1 1 1 1
  ..- attr(*, "source")= chr "Collected at v1"
 $ x    : int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
  ..- attr(*, "source")= chr "Collected at v1"
 $ y    : num [1:5] 0 0 0 1 1
  ..- attr(*, "source")= chr "Collected at v1"
```

Or if we want to use access the column name use `cur_column()` and assign with `<<-`

```
v1 %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), 
  ~ {attr(v1[[cur_column()]], "source") <<- "Collected at v1"
   .x}))
```

-output

```
> str(v1)
tibble [5 × 4] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ id   : int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
  ..- attr(*, "source")= chr "Collected at v1"
 $ visit: num [1:5] 1 1 1 1 1
  ..- attr(*, "source")= chr "Collected at v1"
 $ x    : int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
  ..- attr(*, "source")= chr "Collected at v1"
 $ y    : num [1:5] 0 0 0 1 1
  ..- attr(*, "source")= chr "Collected at v1"
```

---

Or if we want to replicate the same behavior i.e. making use of the original data object name along with its columns names as in `for` loop, use  `reduce`

```
library(purrr)
v1 <- reduce(names(v1), ~ {
         attr(.x[[.y]], "source") <- "Collected at v1"
             .x}, .init = v1)
```

-output

```
> str(v1)
tibble [5 × 4] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ id   : int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
  ..- attr(*, "source")= chr "Collected at v1"
 $ visit: num [1:5] 1 1 1 1 1
  ..- attr(*, "source")= chr "Collected at v1"
 $ x    : int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
  ..- attr(*, "source")= chr "Collected at v1"
 $ y    : num [1:5] 0 0 0 1 1
  ..- attr(*, "source")= chr "Collected at v1"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it directly in a `mutate()`. You need to use `set_attr()` from the `magrittr` package.

```
mt2 <- mtcars %>% mutate(cyl2 = magrittr::set_attr(cyl, "source", "collected at v1"))
```

### for all variables

```
mt2 <- mtcars %>% mutate(across(everything(), 
                         .fns = function(x) magrittr::set_attr(x, "source", "collected at v1")))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, Mike! I marked akrun's as the solution because it worked and he submitted it first, but yours is also really helpful!

Comment: no problem! glad it was useful

Answer (score 2):

If you have attributes that are unique for each column.

Following from other answers [@Akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3732271/akrun) & [@Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5837689/mike):

```
library(dplyr)
v1 <- tibble(
  id = 1:5,
  visit = 1,
  x = 1:5,
  y = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1)
)
```

attributes e.g:

```
attr_v1 <- tibble(col_names = names(v1)) %>%
    mutate(source = paste0("Collected at v", row_number()),
           author = paste0("A_", row_number()))
```

Set these attributes to the respective columns:

```
v1 <- v1 %>%
  mutate(
    across(
      everything(), 
      ~ magrittr::set_attr(.x, "source", 
                           pull(select(filter(attr_v1, 
                              col_names == cur_column()), source)))
    ),
    across(
      everything(), 
      ~ magrittr::set_attr(.x, "author", 
                           pull(select(filter(attr_v1, 
                             col_names == cur_column()), author)))
    )
  )

attributes(v1$id)
attributes(v1$visit)
attributes(v1$x)
attributes(v1$y)
```